# shell-script -cd in all subdirecories of a directory, execute command on their files

Tags: shell, subdirectory, cd

I am new to bash and i am trying to cd to all subdirectories of a parent directory and execute a command in all files these subdirecories contain.But it s not working.

```
for subdir in $parentdirectory
do 
    for file in $subdir
    do
    ngram - lm somefilename.lm - ppl file
    done
done
```

Comment: Are you trying to walk a directory in a specific order, or you just want to make sure the program gets executed at every level?

Comment: I want to be executed at every level.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this, but one would require you to explicitly change to that directory. Assuming `$parentdirectory` is correctly initialized, then you could look into something like:

```
for subdir in ${parentdirectory}
do 
    cd ${subdir}     # go into the subdir
    for file in *    # glob expansion
    do
        ngram - lm somefilename.lm - ppl ${file}
    done
    cd ..            # go back up
done
```

Also have a look at the excellent Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to do this with a small amount of space, you could do something using find -exec.

Such as:

`# add a file called foo into every subdirectory
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'touch "$0/foo"' {} \;`

Or, if you wanted to echo a string into each of those files you just created:

`# find all files and append 'ABC' into them
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "ABC" >> $0' {} \;`

The `find -exec` combo is an extremely powerful tool that can save you on a bit of directory / file navigation, and allows you to achieve what it sounds like is the desired functionality without having to play descend/ascend through the directory structure.

Also, as you can probably guess, this kind of thing can go horribly wrong if you're not careful, so use with great caution.